# how to update another table value by event in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Lets say i have 2 table Movements and Stocks

```
Incomings
-----
id (Primary Key)
trx_number
trx_date
product_id (FK)
qty

Stocks
------
id (Primary Key)
product_id (FK)
begin_stock
in
out
end_stock
```

**in** and **end_stock** fields of **Stocks** table expcted to be updated Whenever **incomings** occured,
currenctly i use laravel Event and Listener to handle this, like so :

```
//Incoming Controller :
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    Incoming::create([
        'trx-number' => 'TRX-001',
        'trx-date' => '2023-07-31',
        'product_id' => '1001',
        'qty' => 10
    ]);

    \App\Events\IncomingOccured::dispatch($attr);
});

//IncomingOccured class will dispatched and will be listened by UpdateProductStock class :
\App\Events\IncomingOccured::class => [
    \App\Listeners\UpdateProductStock::class
],

//Then inside UpdateProductStock class it will updating the model :
$stock = Stock::where('product_id', $item['product_id'])->first();

$stock = Stock::updateOrCreate(['product_id' => $item['product_id']]);

$stock->save();

$stock->increment('in', $requestedQty);
$stock->increment('end_stock', $requestedQty);
```

The goal was achieved, but i feel this is not the best way it is too complicated and event has nothing to do with this
What is a better way to do this ?

Comment: why not update on the controller?

Comment: @krisgjika because its business logic which shouldn't be in the controller in my opinion, thats why i moved them to event, but it feels doesn't right either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean way of checking for changes is using an observer [(see here for the docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers) for your model which can be created with:

```
php artisan make:observer IncomingObserver --model=Incoming
```

Then, we can check when one of these models are created, and affect the stock quantities from there.

As a side note, generally a better approach for doing this would be to use a single source of truth and generate values based on aggregated data. This way, the logs of incomings and outcomings would be where the derived values come from, which would most likely be produced from [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) that runs the queries.

Comment: so if i understand your suggestion correctly,
the stock table shouldn't exists, and instead the stock values must be came from aggregates transactions am i correct ?

Comment: Ideally, yes. If it's entire purpose is to track a log of what has come in / out, it would be much more reliable to track that solely through the logs you already have. Duplication of data in multiple places will often times lead to inconsistency that you will track through the logs anyway.

Comment: do you have any good refference article / guidance to learn about this topics ? it really interesting how the db structure should be designed & optimized

Comment: [Here is a good one that describes this concept](https://edunceputans.medium.com/single-source-of-truth-and-problems-with-implication-in-an-organisation-588883492133). Now combine this with accessors and you have yourself some really easy to work with ways of getting that data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Laravel's best feature here.

That's called an observer. When you change anything on any table, you will get an event for it, like create, update, or delete.

Also in this, you will track the old and new data in the update method for any specific field.

f you are listening for many events on a given model, you may use observers to group all of your listeners into a single class. Observer classes have method names which reflect the Eloquent events you wish to listen for. Each of these methods receives the affected model as their only argument. The make:observer Artisan command is the easiest way to create a new observer class:

```
php artisan make:observer IncomingObserver --model=Incoming
```

This command will place the new observer in your app/Observers directory. If this directory does not exist, Artisan will create it for you. Your fresh observer will look like the following:

```
    <?php
 
namespace App\Observers;
 
use App\Models\Incoming;
 
class IncomingObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Incoming "created" event.
     */
    public function created(Incoming $Incoming): void
    {
        // ...
    }


/**
 * Handle the Incoming "updated" event.
 */
public function updated(Incoming $Incoming): void
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * Handle the Incoming "deleted" event.
 */
public function deleted(Incoming $Incoming): void
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * Handle the Incoming "restored" event.
 */
public function restored(Incoming $Incoming): void
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * Handle the Incoming "forceDeleted" event.
 */
public function forceDeleted(Incoming $Incoming): void
{
    // ...
}
}
```

Register Observers class on provider.

app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        Incoming::observe(IncomingObserver::class);
    }
```

Comment: does the DB transaction is applicable if we use this observer ?

Comment: As seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions) we can ensure it is after the transaction with the line `public $afterCommit = true;` in the observer.

Comment: @MatthewBradley thanks buddy, i shoul've read the docs first, my bad

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to update this, first one generating observer class and handling events there.

```
//creating observer class
php artisan make:observer IncomingObserver -m=Incoming

//Registering it in app service provider's boot() method
Incoming::observe(IncomingObserver::class);
```

Secondly, you can also catch an event in your model class like this.

```
public static function boot() {
       parent::boot();
       //Get current model object in the following events do whatever           
       static::creating(function($item) {});
       static::created(function($item) {});
       static::updating(function($item) {});
       static::updated(function($item) {})
}
```

Comment: the second method is interesting,
out of the box there is no boot method for model, is this generated by artisan command or we have to write them ourselves ?

Comment: It's inherited from parent model as model extends to base model.